# Follower Count instaloader

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instaloader

I want to print the amount of followers the target user has using instaloader.

```
def FollowerCount():
    return(profile.get_followers())
```

```
print(FollowerCount())
```

but I get this

```
<instaloader.nodeiterator.NodeIterator object at 0x000001E26A2CF4F0>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def FollowerCount():
    followers = profile.followers
    print(followers)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).